# react semantic ui checkboxes,how to toggle single element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, semantic-ui

I'm mapping an array and for each element I'm adding a checkbox. Checkbox has an attribute "checked" and depending on state toggles it. But when I clicking for one checkbox , it toggles all checkboxes. How to toggle for a single checkbox?

```
let respondent = data.map((item, idx) => {
  const { personalData, status_id } = item

  return (
    <div key={idx} className="respondents-list_item">

      <Checkbox
        onClick={() => this.addCheckedToArray(status_id)}
        checked={isChecked}
      />

      <div className="respondents-line">
        <div>
          {personalData.name}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
})

addCheckedToArray(id) {
    const { arrayOfStatusId } = this.state

    this.setState({
      isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
    })

    if (arrayOfStatusId.includes(id)) {
      let index = arrayOfStatusId.indexOf(id)

      arrayOfStatusId.splice(index, 1)
    } else {
      arrayOfStatusId.push(id)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are a bit confused about state, you must keep track in your state the list of checked items and update the array not only the isChecked value, in your case, every items will toggle together couse they are looking for the same property to toggle

```
      let respondent = data.map((item, idx) => {
  const { personalData, status_id } = item
  return (
    <div key={idx} className="respondents-list_item">
      <Checkbox
        onClick={() => this.addCheckedToArray(status_id)}
        checked={this.isChecked(status_id)}
      />
      <div className="respondents-line">
        <div>
          {personalData.name}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
})


isChecked = (id) =>{
  return this.state.arrayOfStatusId.includes(id)
}




addCheckedToArray(id) {
    let newState = {...this.state}
    if (newState.arrayOfStatusId.includes(id)) {
      let index = newState.arrayOfStatusId.indexOf(id)
      newState.arrayOfStatusId.splice(index, 1)
    } else {
      newState.arrayOfStatusId.push(id)
    }
    this.setState({
      ...newState
    })
  }
```